# Removing Breaklines at the start of string

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am using HtmlAgilityPack to format html for a text file. <br> nodes are replaced with '\r\n' so it stays formatted in the text file. I want all the breaklines before the first actual char to be removed but my code doesnt do that. The final output for the test should be: 
**Original**:
Hello
Check 
**Expected:**
Hello
Check

```
html = "<br><br><br>Hello<br>Check";
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//br");
if (nodes != null)
{
    foreach(var node in nodes)
    {
        node.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(doc.CreateTextNode("\r\n"), node);
    }
}

html = doc.Documentode.InnerText.TrimStart('r','n');
OutputLog.WriteLine("trimmed: " + html);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want all the breaklines before the first actual char to be removed
>   but my code doesnt do that.

You could easily do this using Regex.

```
html = "<br><br><br>Hello<br>Check";
Regex.Replace(s,"^(?:<br>)+","\r\n") //Returns Hello<br>Check
```

Then you can process your html as you want.